# Is the byte alignment requirement of a given data type guaranteed to be a power of 2?

Tags: c++, c, alignment, memory-alignment

Is the byte alignment requirement of a given data type guaranteed to be a power of 2?

Is there something that provides this guarantee other than it "not making sense otherwise" because it wouldn't line up with system page sizes?

(background: C/C++, so feel free to assume data type is a C or C++ type and give C/C++ specific answers.)

Answer (score 3):

Alignment requirement are based on the hardware.  Most, if not all, "modern" chips have addresses that are divisible by 8, not just a power of 2.  In the past there were non-divisible by 8 chips (I know of a 36 bit architecture).

Comment: The standard most likely doesn't say anything about alignment at all, so you can't use that to make assumptions.  I believe there is a requirement that smaller alignments divide larger ones exactly, though.

Comment: Don't know about C, but C++03 says several things about alignment, and C++0x gets much more specific about the details.

Comment: Some DSPs are not byte-addressable.

Comment: @DwB "Most, if not all, "modern" chips have addresses that are divisible by 8, not just a power of 2."  Confused by this statement because divisible by 8 constitutes perfectly alignment to a power of 2.

Comment: @Jeremiah: No such requirement, except that all alignments must be expressible as (arrays of) unsigned chars underneath.

Comment: 4 is a power of 2.  4 is, however; not divisible by 8 and may not be a valid alignment.

Comment: @Loadmaster: From 3.11 of the current C++0x draft N3242: "Every alignment value shall be a non-negative integral power of two."  I didn't know that before.  There is a weaker requirement about divisibility in the next paragraph.

Comment: @DwB Alright, that says that not all powers of 2 are valid alignments but doesn't say anything about the opposite, all valid alignments being powers of 2, which is what my question asked.

Comment: @DwB Also, come to think of it, your last sentence mentioning a 36-bit architechture leads be to believe that you're talking about alignment of types in bits rather than bytes-- please clarify if that's wrong (and a 36-bit type would, I would take a guess, be made of 4 9-bit bytes, of which the byte alignment is still a power of 2).  If bit alignment (byte size) is what you are referring to, could you illuminate on how it might be an issue to memory alignment issues in the context of programming?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock Thanks, I don't use C++0x yet, but I was looking for these types of answers. +1

Answer (score 2):

Things you can assume about alignment, per the C standard:

- The alignment requirement of any type divides the size of that type (as determined by `sizeof`).
- The character types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` have no alignment requirement. (This is actually just a special case of the first point.)

In the modern real world, integer and pointer types have sizes that are powers of two, and their alignment requirements are usually equal to their sizes (the only exception being `long long` on 32-bit machines). Floating point is a bit less uniform. On 32-bit machines, all floating point types typically have an alignment of 4, whereas on 64-bit machines, the alignment requirement of floating point types is typically equal to the size of the type (4, 8, or 16).

The alignment requirement of a `struct` should be the least common multiple of the alignment requirements of its members, but a compiler is allowed to impose stricter alignment. However, normally each cpu architecture has an ABI standard that includes alignment rules, and compilers which do not adhere to the standard will generate code that cannot be linked with code built by compilers which follow the ABI standard, so it would be very unusual for a compiler to break from the standard except for very special-purpose use.

By the way, a useful macro that will work on any sane compiler is:

```
#define alignof(T) ((char *)&((struct { char x; T t; } *)0)->t - (char *)0)
```

Comment: Not all compilers are sane, like those starting to implement the new C++0x keyword `alignof`. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson is that a criticism of the new C++0x standard, or poking fun at the illegality of his macro in a C++0x compiler?

Comment: Even if it is a keyword, this is one keyword where defining it as a macro probably would not break anything... I can't imagine `alignof` being useful in macros defined in the headers, and even if it were useful, it would have the same behavior as the keyword except perhaps under really nasty operator overloading...

Answer (score 0):

The alignment of a field inside a "struct", optimized for size could very well be on a odd boundary. other then that your "It wouldn't make sense" would probably apply, but I think there is NO guarantee, especially if the program was small model, optimized for size. - Joe

Comment: Just checked, their still making the Z80 (and many of it's embedded system hybrid offshoots) and NSC has a line of COP8... chips that seem to have replaced the NSC 800 (modeled after the Z80). these chips have no advantage in word aligning the data elements, so if your programing a controller for a microwave oven or similar device using an 8 bitter, then don't count on word alignment.

Answer (score 0):

For basic data types (ints, floats, <del>doubles</del>) usually the alignment matches the size of the type. For classes/structs, the alignment is at least the lowest common multiple of the alignment of all its members (that's the standard)

- In Visual Studio you can set your own alignment for a type, but it has to be a power of 2, between 1 and 8192.
- In GCC there is a similar mechanism, but it has no such requirement (at least in theory)

Comment: Size and alignment of `double` do not match on most 32-bit machines. (Size is 8 and alignment is 4).

Comment: Thought it does. My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard doesn't require alignment, but allows struct/unions/bit fields to silently add padding bytes to get a correct alignment. The compiler is also free to align all your data types on even addresses should it desire.

That being said, this is CPU dependent, and I don't believe there exists a CPU that has an alignment requirement on odd addresses. There are plenty of CPUs with *no* alignment requirements however, and the compiler may then place variables at any address.

Comment: Assuming you mean mathematically odd, and not strange odd: the question was not of whether alignment requirements were a multiple of 2 (ie. even vs. odd), but a **power** of 2.  CPUs with no alignment requirements would still satisfy the condition of all valid alignments being a power of 2 (2^0 is 1).

Comment: @Jason. Yes, mathematically odd. Naturally alignment will be 2,4,8 and so on. Have you ever head about 48-bit CPUs? 80-bit CPUs? Me neither. It makes sense to speak of even alignment, as a memory segment with alignment requirements must be allocated at an even address, no matter the byte alignment.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. It depends on the hardware.

However, most modern CPUs either do byte alignment (e.g., Intel x86 CPUs), or word alignment (e.g., Motorola, IBM/390, RISC, etc.).

Even with word alignment, it can be complicated. For example, a 16-bit word would be aligned on a 2-byte (even) address, a 32-bit word on a 4-byte boundary, but a 64-bit value may only require 4-byte alignment instead of an 8-byte aligned address.

For byte-aligned CPUs, it's also a function of the compiler options. The default alignmen for struct members can usually be specified (usually also with a compiler-specific #pragma).